# @Html.DropDownListFor does not contain a definition for

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Not sure what I'm missing here. I'm trying to display a dropdown list with records from my country table.

**My Model**

```
public ClientSMSAccountCustom()
{
    this.Countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
}     
public IList<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
//get all countries
var countries = rad.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryID).ToList();

foreach (var c in countries)
{
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Text = c.Description;
    item.Value = c.CountryID.ToString();
    model.Countries.Add(item);
}
```

**My View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, Model.Countries)
```

**This is the exact error**

> 'TotalDesk.Models.ClientSMSAccountCustom' does not contain a definition for 'CountryID' and no extension method 'CountryID' accepting a first argument of type 'TotalDesk.Models.ClientSMSAccountCustom' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`TotalDesk.Models.ClientSMSAccountCustom` is the model class

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. Your `ClientSMSAccountCustom` model does not contain a property named `CountryID`!

Comment: @StephenMuecke what I'm I missing? How do I get it to read the Countries property?

Comment: Add a `public int CountryID { get; set; }` property to your `ClientSMSAccountCustom` model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the property CounrtyID in my model class.

Thanks Stephen!

```
    public ClientSMSAccountCustom()
    {
        this.Countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
```